# How can specify the base class from whom I derive in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have a homework for my programming course that asks me to designs an abstract from whom derive two classes, and from those two derived classes derives another class.

This brings the Deadly Diamond of Death problem. Which can be solved by virtual inheritance, though I need instance the objects of my first two classes to a pointer of my abstract class. And this can't be done with any kind of virtual inheritance. So, if there is a way to specify the base class from which the multiple inheritance class will derive, it would be astronomically useful.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void foo(){};
        virtual void bar(){};
};

class Der1 : public Base {  
    public:
        virtual void foo();

};

void Der1::foo()
{
    cout << "Der1::foo()" << endl;
}

class Der2 : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void bar();
};

void Der2::bar()
{
        cout << "Der2::bar()" << endl;
}

class Join : virtual Der1, virtual Der2 {

    private:
        int atribb;



};

int main()
{
        Base* obj = new Join();
        ((Der1 *)(obj))->foo();
}
```

Compiler error:

nueve.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

nueve.cpp:43:30: error: ‘Base’ is an ambiguous base of ‘Join’

Base* obj = new Join();

Comment: Look up pure virtual functions and seriously consider having Base just having those.

Comment: When you say "And this can't be done with any kind of virtual inheritance." what do you mean? I initially read it as saying that your class does not permit you to use virtual inheritance for this assignment, but maybe you meant that you do in fact want to use virtual inheritance but can't do what you are trying to do?

Comment: " that asks me to designs an abstract from whom derive two classes" - but this is not what you've done, `Base` is not abstract. You should make `Base`'s functions pure virtual (add `=0`). I'm not certain whether you still need virtual inheritance in that case.

Comment: "Diamond of Death" is usually a colorful way of saying "I don't understand multiple inheritance".

Answer (score 3):

Use virtual inheritance.

```
class Der1 : public virtual Base {  
    public:
        virtual void foo();

};



class Der2 : public virtual Base {
    public:
        virtual void bar();
};
```

**If virtual is declared while deriving from base class, as shown in below example, the most derived class object contains only one base class sub object, which helps in resolving the ambiguity in your case.**

After doing some code changes, your final executable code:

Code changes in below sample:

Added **vitual** key word, while deriving the child classes.
Removed "virtual" keyword while deriving most derived class.
Modified main to invoke the member function properly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void foo(){};
        virtual void bar(){};
};

class Der1 : public virtual Base {  
    public:
        virtual void foo();

};

void Der1::foo()
{
    cout << "Der1::foo()" << endl;
}

class Der2 : public virtual Base {
    public:
        virtual void bar();
};

void Der2::bar()
{
        cout << "Der2::bar()" << endl;
}

class Join : public Der1, public Der2 {

    private:
        int atribb;



};

int main()
{
        Base* obj = new Join();
        obj->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking for, although you seem to be saying that virtual inheritance from `Base` is not suitable. So, assuming that's correct, you can replace `Base* obj = new Join();` with `Base* obj = (Der1*)new Join();` and you'll get a pointer to the `Base` object that's the base of `Der1`. Similarly, you can replace it with `Base* obj = (Der2*)new Join();` and you'll get a pointer to the `Base` object thats the base of `Der2`.